# conditional default constraint based on value from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, constraints

I have three tables

```
---
TAI
---
tai_id    int
dai_id    int

---
DAI
---
dai_id    int
DaiType   varchar(1)

---
TAD
---
tad_id    int
tai_id    int
StoreDate DateTime  <<--default constraint in this field and table
```

Everytime I insert a record in the TAD table, I need to put the current date in the `StoreDate` field, But, only if the field `DaiType` from the `DAI` table is = `'S'`. For every other value in the field `DaiType` from the `DAI` table, the value in `TAD.StoreDate` should be default as null.

How is this done using only constraints? I don't want to write triggers or any kind of back end jobs.

Comment: Sounds like a no-can-do to me. You could try to use a function as default, but you cannot pass column values to that function. But the function somehow needed to know which record to check in `dai`.

Comment: can the function get the value being inserted in the field tai_id of the `TAD` table?

Comment: As I said you cannot pass columns. If you try you will get an error like: "The name "<column_name>" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted."

Comment: no I meant like when the function is called during an insert, I get the current rowid being inserted and from that rowid, find out the `tai_id` inserted and then using drill down to the `DAI` table and pull out the `DaiType` value. Return true if `value='S '` and insert the default value if the function returned true.

Comment: You mean like calling the function in the `VALUES` clause of an `INSERT` or in the column list of an `INSERT ... SELECT`? Yeah, you can call a function there and supply the `tad_id` you're about to insert. You can also use a subquery there or, in case of an `INSERT ... SELECT`, join `tai` and `dai`.

Comment: It's not going to happen without triggers (or something even more complex).

Comment: This simply can not be done using a default constraint.  Triggers is the way to do it.

Comment: This question/requirement is like asking how to watch TV without TV, or Winning in the football mondial without touching a ball. It is not a matter of `impossible` but a matter of something `without any sense`. If this your requirement then you should redesign the system to have different requirement. You should think about what brought to this requirement. You should focus on the question "WHY" until you get the source of the requirement.